# Mysql query to percentage of Two columns

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count, average

I am trying to work out a MYSQL query
the table called ratings is nothing complicated
columns are

```
id    comment    articleid    userid    vote
```

What I am trying to achieve is to count all votes for an article divided by yes votes for that article / 100 (the vote column is either 1 or 0) - just a percentage really - and then group all results for each article.

So the return would be something like

```
articleid   pct
21          80
15          45
17          75
```

something all the lines of this

```
SELECT articleid, (count(*) as votes / yes votes) * 100 as pct 
from ratings
group by articleid
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Since you are dealing with `0`/`1` values, you can just use `avg()`:

```
select articleid, avg(vote) ratio from ratings group by articleid
```

This gives you a value between `0` and `1`. You can turn it to a percentage by multiplying it by `100`:

```
select articleid, avg(vote) * 100 pct from ratings group by articleid
```